# refresh the table in view controller by using refresh bar button

Tags: iphone, ios, uibarbuttonitem, uibarbuttonitemstyle

I want to add a refresh bar button in my view controller
I put in the `viewdidload()` this code:

```
UIBarButtonItem *refreshButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refreshTable)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = refreshButton;
```

and the refreshtable function is :

```
- (void) refreshTable
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];

    NSLog(@"table is refreshing ....");
}
```

this is a screenshot of the refresh button:
[image]

but it doesn't work, shall i add something else in the refreshtable function?, the table view doesn't refreshed!, the message "table is refreshing ...." appears everytime i click on the refresh button, but the table doesn't load new data!

when refreshing, can I have this icon somewhere?
[image]

If I had two table view in my view controller, and I want when I click on the refresh button, just the first table to be reloaded,

[image]

I put the same you code that you suggested, but it doesn't work here! should I do something else?

Comment: sorry, I edited just now

Comment: Change the log to NSLog(@"table (%@) is refreshing ....", self.tableView); and see what it says

Comment: You need to explain why do you expect something different to show up in the table on `reloadData`. Did the data source change between the time the table was shown before and the moment you tapped `[refresh]`?

Comment: @CarinaM: Where are you getting those data, that you need to display on tableview ? In which method you are fetching new data ?

Comment: @MidhunMP   <UITableView: 0x8966a00; frame = (0 20; 320 460); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x83798c0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x837a1e0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>

Comment: @MidhunMP the data is getting from json file

Comment: @dasblinkenlight this table contains data from json file, and this data is changed always, so I want when I press on the refresh button to get the new data

Comment: @CarinaM: Ok, then in which method you are getting the json ?

Comment: @MidhunMP     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://....../fastnews.php"]];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });  
-(void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData{
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    fastResults = [json objectForKey:@"nodes"];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

Comment: @CarinaM: In which method you added this code `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{ NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://....../fastnews.php"]]; [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES]; });` ? Is it in the `refreshTable` ?

Comment: @MidhunMP in viewdidLoad(), what should I put in refreshTable()?

Comment: @MidhunMP wait I will try it, then give u a feedback

Comment: @CarinaM: Ok, all the best :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you added the data fetching logic in your `viewDidLoad` (according to your comments).

The viewDidLoad method will be called when the view is loading. It' won't be called unless you dismiss the view and present it again(it won't be calles if you call the `reloadData` it's just for reloading the `UITableView`).

When you call the `reloadData` the data source is still with old data, it is not updated.

So implement your `refreshTable` method like:

```
- (void) refreshTable
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
         NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://....../fastnews.php"]];
         [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
}

-(void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData
{
   NSError *error;
   NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
  fastResults = [json objectForKey:@"nodes"];
  [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: please before you leave, do you have an idea how can I display the refresh icon (to let the user knows that the view is refreshing), check screen above

Comment: please can you reply on my question!

Comment: @CarinaM: You can use the `UIActivityIndicator` for this.

Comment: can you send me a simple code how can I implement it in my above code?

Comment: @CarinaM: add this code `UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] 
                                     initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
        spinner.center = CGPointMake(160, 240);
        spinner.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
        [self.view addSubview:spinner];
        [spinner startAnimating];` as the first line of `refreshTable` method

Comment: and how can I stop the animation of it? because still animated

Comment: thank you, it is done, I put stopanimating here: `   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http:....."]];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];[spinner stopAnimating];
    });`

Comment: hello again, please can you check above, I just edited my question please

Answer (score 0):

try this .

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] 
             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your `dataSourceAaaay` in `refreshTable` method before `reload` table.